# show different arrangement if image and text is in mobile screen using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following code and I am unable to get description below image in mobile screen. How can I make changes to the code ? The way it looks for full screen/desktop is correct. For size "sm" I want it to reorder text and image.

The order I'm looking for : Desktop - Title&desc left and image right.

Mobile - Title on top then image then the description.

Code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 id="title">Title ....................................... more text </h1> 
        <h3 id="description">description ....................................... more description.................... ....................................... more description ....................................... more description....................................... </h3> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="http://www.unoosa.org/res/timeline/index_html/space-2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: @AakashThakur here you go http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbrPwK

Comment: But your codepen link works as expected. I mean you don't have `float-left` and `float-right` in the code provided above but they are in your codepen link. Isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed arrangement of html and gave `classes` to `float` image to `right` and `text` to `left` or you can use `pull-right` and `pull-left` classes provided by `twitter-bootstrap`.

Also there are some `hidden` classes provided by `twitter-bootstrap` you can use them to achieve your desired layout.

**[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp)**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
.float-right {
  float: right
}
.float-left {
  float: left
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 float-right">
        <h1 id="title" class="hidden-md hidden-lg">Title....................................... more text</h1>
        <img src="http://www.unoosa.org/res/timeline/index_html/space-2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 float-left">
        <h1 id="title" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Title....................................... more text</h1>
        <h3 id="description">description.......................................more description....................       ......................................more description     .......................................                         more description.......................................</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you want Image to be on `left` and text to be on `right`?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:http://jsfiddle.net/wVVbT/156/

Tried it with jQuery and it seems to work:

jQuery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        if($(window).width()<992){
            $('.image').after($('#description').get());
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {

   var hthree=$('#description').get();

  if($(window).width()<992)
  {

    $('.image').after(hthree);
  }else{ 


    $('#title').after(hthree);
  }
});
});
```